# Is there a cleverer Ruby algorithm than brute-force for finding correlation in multidimensional data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, cluster-analysis, matching

My platform here is Ruby - a webapp using Rails 3.2 in particular.

I'm trying to match objects (people) based on their ratings for certain items. People may rate all, some, or none of the same items as other people. Ratings are integers between 0 and 5. The number of items available to rate, and the number of users, can both be considered to be non-trivial.

A quick illustration -

[image: Data illustration]

The brute-force approach is to iterate through all people, calculating differences for each item. In Ruby-flavoured pseudo-code -

```
MATCHES = {}
for each (PERSON in (people except USER)) do
  for each (RATING that PERSON has made) do
    if (USER has rated the item that RATING refers to) do
      MATCHES[PERSON's id] += difference between PERSON's rating and USER's rating
    end
  end
end
lowest values in MATCHES are the best matches for USER
```

The problem here being that as the number of items, ratings, and people increase, this code will take a very significant time to run, and ignoring caching for now, this is code that has to run a lot, since this matching is the primary function of my app.

I'm open to cleverer algorithms and cleverer databases to achieve this, but doing it algorithmically and as such allowing me to keep everything in MySQL or PostgreSQL would make my life a lot easier.  The only thing I'd say is that the data does need to persist.

If any more detail would help, please feel free to ask.  Any assistance greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, that's an NP-complete problem. It can only be solved in polynomial time. Since you don't care about which ratings underlie the differences, one approach you could take would be to calculate each user's Euclidean distance from the 0th point in an n-dimension space, where n is the number of ratings being compared. So for example, Person 1's Euclidean distance is 6 (square root of 3^2 + 1 ^2 + 4^2 + 3^2 = 1^2). Person 2's is 5.36, Person 3's is 8.12.

Comment: It's hard to visualize, but if you think of just 3 ratings, then each Euclidean distance represents a sphere around the epicenter (0,0,0). Since you don't care about weighting ratings and only care about absolute differences (so 3-2 is the same as 5-4), you want to find people whose distance point is on the same "sphere." Now expand that to n-dimensions. Theory still holds, find the people on the same "plane."

Comment: There appear to be many related questions with good answers already, particularly [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174123/matching-two-elements-people-together-based-on-similarity-of-preferences?rq=1) - check the related questions tab on the side :)

Comment: @KyleHale Finding the nearest neighbors is not NP-hard, but at most in `O(n*n*d)` where `d` is the cost of computing a single distance/similarity.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [KD-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree).  It's specifically designed to speed up neighbour-finding in N-Dimensional spaces, like your rating system (Person 1 is 3 units along the X axis, 4 units along the Y axis, and so on).

You'll likely have to do this in an actual programming language.  There are spatial indexes for some DBs, but they're usually designed for geographic work, like [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) (which uses [GiST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GiST) indexing), and only support two or three dimensions.

That said, I did find [this tantalizing blog post](http://blog.opengeo.org/2012/03/13/postgis-2-0-new-features-3d4d-indexing/) on PostGIS.  I was then unable to find any other references to this, but maybe your luck will be better than mine...

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Technically your task is matching long strings made out of characters of a 5 letter alphabet. This kind of stuff is researched extensively in the area of computational biology. (Typically with 4 letter alphabets). If you do not know the book [http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-Strings-Trees-Sequences-Computational/dp/0521585198](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521585198) then you might want to get hold of a copy. IMHO this is THE standard book on fuzzy matching / scoring of sequences.

Comment: With regard to the Euclidian distance. One of the ideas from the book is to switch Fourier transforms. If A and B are two persons ratings as n-dimensional vectors then 
||A-B||^2 = ||A||^2 + ||B||^2 - 2<A|B>

Comment: I am struggling with the edit functionality. Would someone with sufficient privileges please delete this plus my comment above? Only the comment, not my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is your data sparse? With rating, most of the time not every user rates every object.

Naively comparing each object to every other is `O(n*n*d)`, where `d` is the number of operations. However, a key trick of all the Hadoop solutions is to transpose the matrix, and work only on the non-zero values in the columns. Assuming that your sparsity is `s=0.01`, this reduces the runtime to `O(d*n*s*n*s)`, i.e. by a factor of `s*s`. So if your sparsity is 1 out of 100, your computation will be theoretically 10000 times faster.

Note that the resulting data will still be a `O(n*n)` distance matrix, so strictl speaking the problem is still quadratic.

The way to beat the quadratic factor is to use index structures. The k-d-tree has already been mentioned, but I'm not aware of a version for categorical / discrete data and missing values. Indexing such data is not very well researched AFAICT.